# Keras fine-tuning InceptionV3 tensor dimension error

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am trying to fine-tune a model in Keras:

```
    inception_model = InceptionV3(weights=None, include_top=False, input_shape=(150, 
150, 1))

    x = inception_model.output
    x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
    x = Dense(256, activation='relu', name='fc1')(x)
    x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
    predictions = Dense(10, activation='softmax', name='predictions')(x)
    classifier = Model(inception_model.input, predictions)


    ####training training training ... save weights


    classifier.load_weights("saved_weights.h5")
  
    classifier.layers.pop()
    classifier.layers.pop()
    classifier.layers.pop()
    classifier.layers.pop()
    ###enough poping to reach standard InceptionV3 

    x = classifier.output
    x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
    x = Dense(256, activation='relu', name='fc1')(x)
    x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
    predictions = Dense(10, activation='softmax', name='predictions')(x)
    classifier = Model(classifier.input, predictions)
```

But I get the error:

```
ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer global_average_pooling2d_3: expected ndim=4, found ndim=2
```

Comment: What's the shape of the input data you are giving to this model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You [shouldn't use](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/2371#issuecomment-211120172) `pop()` method on models created using functional API (i.e. `keras.models.Model`). Only Sequential models (i.e. `keras.models.Sequential`) have a built-in [`pop()`](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/7205d903fbc079bb99fbae0e3c02e6d2b4d227f0/keras/engine/sequential.py#L192) method (usage: `model.pop()`). Instead, use index or the names of the layers to access a specific layer:

```
classifier.load_weights("saved_weights.h5")
x = classifier.layers[-5].output   # use index of the layer directly
x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
```